# UFT image edit , ie updating image

Tags: hp-uft

I am using UFT I have captured an image object , but now I want to update this image with another image, so that the code uses the updated image than the previous one, all other objects remain the same, I couldn't find an option for that , could you please guide me how to update the image with something else[image: the image] thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

UFT typically doesn't use images to identify objects (with [one exception](https://lanzkron.wordpress.com/2019/04/03/image-based-testing-with-insight/)), especially since they image you're sharing is from UFT's Object Repository.

I'll assume you want to update the object repository (otherwise I don't understand the question). Check out [Shared Object Repositories](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.50-14.53/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/Object_Repositories.htm) on how to use an external object repository which can be updated independantly from the test.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess the question it's about the update of the object in any Repository.

But You can update every object like this, if they belong at same type.

Short answer, you replace your object. Long answer check the link Motti gave you.

[Update Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIeL3.png)